# Determine order of execution of Spock tests

Tags: grails, spock, geb

Is there a way to set the order in which tests are executed within an Spock Specification?

For example:

```
class MySpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def 'test A'...

    def 'test B'...
}
```

I want 'test A' to be execute always before 'test B'

This is because I'm doing some functional tests with Geb and Spock and data is not rolled back between tests.

Comment: Oops, seems it's not about Kobayashi Maru test from Star Trek.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `@Stepwise` annotation on a spec and spock will run each of the test definitions of the Spec in the order they are specified. Look at [this example](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/StepwiseExtensionSpec.groovy).

Comment: And for Geb, use `Geb(Reporting)Spec` together with `@Stepwise`.

Comment: When extending from IntegrationSpec, @Stepwise works, but when extending GebReportingSpec it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: In fact, it do work with GebReportingSpec. The problem I was having had something to do with my spec extending a base spec. My subSpec has a setup method and i think that that (added to the inheritance) could cause my problem.

Comment: It's a know issue between @Stepwise and inheritance: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spockframework/UqogYwH77bY. Also http://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=183. In fact, issued by Pangea.